# Are there any hadiths/verses that indicate a Muslim's approach to the media?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, tv, social-media

Is there any way of telling how the Muhammad (pbuh) would want us to treat the media in its entirety e.g. newspapers, TV shows etc. and are there any hadiths in the past that could be used similarly for us today e.g. skepticism?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Medi1Saif In their time there were certainly independent messengers who would announce news to them. But I am not referring specifically to the technology - look at the question - things like skepticism may intertwine with hadiths.
It is entirely possible to build up an interpretation that the Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) would have had towards the media if we place the hadiths in the context of today.

Comment: I read it, so you may in first place look for sources from hadith and quran where a ruling for that can be deduced from! What do you mean with "skepticism" could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

A major source for that would be Verse ([49:6](http://legacy.quran.com/49/6))

> O you who have believed, if there comes to you a disobedient one with information, investigate, lest you harm a people out of ignorance and become, over what you have done, regretful.

where a ruling for handling with news is clearly defined: If this person is not trustworthy one should investigate and review the information he came with before taking it as true! The word disobedient in the above translation can be replace by any other word which may question about the trustworthiness of the transmitter of the news,information or message!

Taking the time to check is a sunnah according [this](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/27/118) hadith from Sunan at-Tirmdhi.
 For example: based on this scholars have made a scale in hadith sciences to check the trustworthiness of narrators -> ilm-a-rijal or ilam la jarh wa-ta'adil.

**Note** that Islam on the other hand prohibits [spying and making negative assumptions](http://legacy.quran.com/49/12) this means if we check an information we shouldn't spy with the intention to find out something negative about somebody in order to disclose his secrets in public! The linked Verse also means that we should always or in first place think positive and good about others unless we have a proof and that we should conceal the faults of other Muslims (see for example [here](http://sunnah.com/urn/1326430)) instead of disclosing them.

The Prophet Sulayman (Solomon) (Peace be upon him) declared that he will check the given information, when the hoopoe came with the news from Saba' (Sheba) as described in the Verses you may find before and after the Verse with this statement ([27:27](http://legacy.quran.com/27/27))

> [Solomon] said, "We will see whether you were truthful or were of the liars.

An other statement from the quran would be the wording:

> Say, "Produce your proof, if you should be truthful."

which is quoted in ([2:111](http://legacy.quran.com/2/111)), ([21:24](http://legacy.quran.com/21/24)), ([27:64](http://legacy.quran.com/27/64)) and ([28:75](http://legacy.quran.com/28/75)).

Islam has also prohibited lying (see for example in Sahih Muslim [here](http://sunnah.com/muslim/45/136) and [here](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1547)) or better didn't encourage talking about others (see for example in [Sahih al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/6)) and asked Muslims to leave what doesn't concern them (see for example [here](http://sunnah.com/urn/516170)).

Some references (in Arabic):

- Rules on [how to deal with rumors](http://www.assakina.com/taseel/24534.html).
- The teachings of [Islam on treating rumors](https://www.3seer.net/articles/76399).
- Shari'a rules on transmitting [information/news](http://www.alimam.ws/ref/1571).

Links to some other relevant Verses from the quran: ([4:83](http://legacy.quran.com/4/83)) and ([24:12](http://legacy.quran.com/24/12))

And Allah knows best!